# C# FileStream behavior End of file

Tags: c#, filestream

There is a behavior of C# `Filestream` I don't get. I have a file. This file contains a string with a length of three. When I open a file stream and overwrite it with an string with a length of six chars, it contains the new string but only the first three chars. It is truncated to the previous length.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.open(rootPath + filePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
   bool write = fs.CanWrite;
   bool canSeek = fs.CanSeek;

   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sixchars);

   fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   fs.Flush();               
}
```

So why is this so and how can I work around?

I tried it with `FileMode.Create` too. `CanWrite` and `CanSeek` are `true`;

**EDIT**

Ok here an Code Sample that compiles. I created the file in windows explorer and wrote "123" into it before.

```
 string  path = @"C:\1\test.txt";

 using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path , FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("666666");

            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            fs.Flush();
        }
```

I also tried

```
            File.WriteAllText(path , "666666");
```

and

```
            byte[] datas = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("666666");
            File.WriteAllBytes(path , datas);
```

After all the result is still 666 instead of 666666.

Comment: The code you've given won't compile. (Making the obvious change to it, it works fine for me.) Please provide us with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Jodrell: `sixchars` is obviously a literal string of eight chars.

Comment: @PaulRuane, possibly or maybe three.

Comment: Ok i added a code which compiles.

Comment: The problem is obviously in how you ascertain the results. The code ought to work.

Comment: write `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\path\to\your\file.txt", "666666");` Then check the file. If it containt `666666` - check that you have correct path in your `path` variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(rootPath, filePath), sixchars, Encoding.ASCII);
```

of

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(rootPath, filePath), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sixchars));
```